# Cant add blocks to custom theme. Only admin/default theme showing up on the admin/build/blocks page

Tags: blocks, theming, 5

I’ve done a ton of searching, checking, changing, installing/reinstalling backups, frowning, and soul searching.

After several years successful experience with this site, I’m having the dreaded “Only admin/default theme showing up on the admin/build/blocks page” issue.

And, unfortunately, I’m here to ask for mercy because I’m still on Drupal 5.23.  (Not totally clueless… I would love to move on, but several critical modules have not been brought forward to D6/7.)   Also (for any of you who are moved to contribute by the political climate lately) this is an amazing site for empowering the social, environmental and economic justice movements with advanced collaboration services.  Just beginning to go live … in front of several groups for consideration.  See what I mean =>  http://test01.groupsalive.com/grsj

**The Symptoms:**
1)  No matter that the current default theme and admin theme, admin/build/block always shows me the regions and dropdown options for the default or admin themes … regardless of whether I have specifically selected a different them (with different regions) to modify block settings and locations.  If I attempt to change block settings for any other theme, the settings get applied to the admin or default themes depending on which is active.
2)  None of the settings for themes and blocks created before the problem occurred have been affected (yet).  Existing blocks and themes appear normal.

The Symptoms (as described in http://drupal.org/node/219910 in case the language makes more sense)

**Steps to reproduce:**

1) Set an admin theme in admin/settings/admin
2) Enable a module that calls a theme function from hook_init(). The Teleport module does this by calling drupal_get_form().
3) Navigate to the block administration page at admin/build/block.

**Expected behavior:** The block admin page should render in the non-admin theme, and moving blocks around and saving should apply the save to the non-admin theme.

**What happened instead:** The block admin page renders in the admin theme, and when changes to blocks are saved, the changes are applied to the admin theme and do not show up on non-admin pages. This happens even though the secondary tab is titled with the name of the non-admin theme. This makes it impossible to change blocks for the non-admin theme.

**What I’ve tried:**

Looking at all changes in modules, data/content, and themes since the last database backup that works.

1)  disabled and uninstalled (where possible) all modules installed since site worked.
2)  Disabled all themes installed since site worked
3)  Disabled all themes except one standard theme (garland) and one custom theme (litejazz).
4)  Manually removed database tables installed by modules (above) that did not uninstall themselves
5)  Removed all data/content  added since site worked

Hoping someone can notice this or reply because this seems to still be a very active issue/bug for Drupal 6  (gathered the best related links I could find here into one place for ref).  Quite a few of the instances describe actions (or are discussed) as if they are module problems, others seem not to.  Seems, if I  understand correctly that, maybe, modules are triggering a condition that’s an inherent problem in how core implements the administration of these block settings.  Some back and forth over whether this is a bug or a feature/consequence of normal Drupal behavior.  And some agonizing over whether this “normal” behavior is good.

1)  Have not seen any fixes that seem to be more than workarounds for specific cases.
2)  Seems that the problem has been replicated intentionally and unintentionally.

Blocks page is broken for multiple themes.
see: [drupal.org/node/816036](http://drupal.org/node/816036)

Breaks the block admin page when separate admin theme is used
see: [drupal.org/node/489964](http://drupal.org/node/489964)

block_menu() broken: depends on theme at time of menu cache rebuild
see: [drupal.org/node/698406](http://drupal.org/node/698406)

Wrong theme shown on Administer Blocks page (site building / blocks)
see: [drupal.org/node/281643](http://drupal.org/node/281643)

path_to_theme() call breaking blocks page
see: [drupal.org/node/178364](http://drupal.org/node/178364)

blocks cannot be configure if administration theme used
see: [drupal.org/node/219756](http://drupal.org/node/219756)

Calling theme function from hook_init() interferes with administration theme
see: [drupal.org/node/219910](http://drupal.org/node/219910)

Administration theme messing with your block configuration?
see: [krimson.be/articles/administration-theme-messing-your-block-configuration](http://krimson.be/articles/administration-theme-messing-your-block-configuration)

blocks admin weight and region selectors broken?
see: [findrupalcms.com/blocks-admin-weight-and-region-selectors-broken](http://findrupalcms.com/blocks-admin-weight-and-region-selectors-broken)

Thanks all.